# unable to run scripts from jenkins

Tags: ios, jenkins, sikuli

We are using sikuli tool for mobile automation on our MAC OSX 10.7.3 I have written a shell script to open simulator and to run scripts on simulator:

```
SikuliScript.sh 
/Users/ezprintsqa/Downloads/FoneMonkey/bin/iphonesim launch /Users/ezprintsqa/Documents/Xcode/DerivedData/SnapCards-btmjdowsgmixpvdyfxfvhxtoihab/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SnapCardsFoneMonkey.app&

/Users/ezprintsqa/Downloads/Sikuli-IDE.app/sikuli-ide.sh -r /Users/ezprintsqa/Downloads/SikuliWorkSpace/SnapcardsTestSuite1.sikuli
```

When I execute from command line I can see simulator opening and scripts getting executed on simulator.
But when I run from Jenkins I am getting the following error:

```
[JavaAppLauncher Error] CFBundleCopyResourceURL() failed loading MRJApp.properties file
[DEBUG] Could not start simulator session: Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain     Code=5 "Operation failed with underlying error 4294956486." UserInfo=0x100305c70    {NSLocalizedDescription=Operation failed with underlying error 4294956486.,    NSUnderlyingError=0x100300610 "The operation couldn‚Äôt be completed. (OSStatus error     -10810.)"}
[LaunchRunner Error] No main class specified
[JavaAppLauncher Error] CallStaticVoidMethod() threw an exception
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.run(LaunchRunner.java:113)
at apple.launcher.LaunchRunner.callMain(LaunchRunner.java:51)
at apple.launcher.JavaApplicationLauncher.main(JavaApplicationLauncher.java:61)
```

Any suggestions will be very helpful

Comment: Based on your script, I am guessing that the simulator is looking for the MRJApp.properties file in the current directory, which is always the Jenkins workspace by default. Try using cd to change to the appropriate directory before launching.

Comment: I tried by adding cd but still the problem replicates. Can you please suggest me with any other solution

Comment: I am guessing based on issues I have seen in the past here, but this is starting to sound like a permissions issue. Did you install java and sikuli with the same user which jenkins runs under?

Comment: No jenkins is intalled on /shared/jenkins where sikuli and ios are installed using /testqa.  I tried intalling jenkins also with "testqa" user but just running the downloaded package itself is creating a  new user for jenkins

Comment: It's ok to run with different users, but you will need to grant read permissions to the Jenkins user on certain files, and possibly read/write on some as well. Unfortunately I am not familiar enough with Sikuli to tell you which files would need to permissions changed. You can prove that this is in fact permissions related by running your scripts manually using the Jenkins user and checking if they fail.

Answer (score 2):

It definitely looks like a permission issue. The official Jenkins installer for Mac sets up Jenkins to run either as user "daemon" or user "jenkins". You need to make tools needed by Jenkins readable and executable by that user. Also, they need to be in a directory which is readable and executable by that user.

However, even if you get the permissions fixed, you will probably have further problems with your test run. The official Jenkins installer for Mac sets up Jenkins to run as a launch daemon. These run in the system context and they have no access to any desktop or GUI session, which means it is not possible to draw windows on the screen => Any tool that displays windows, like iPhone Simulator or Sikuli is going to fail.

You could try my unofficial Jenkins.app instead, which should solve your problem. It is available at https://github.com/stisti/jenkins-app (download it under the Downloads tab.)

Comment: This solution is helpful. Thanks for your response